# Derivative of the unit vector tangent

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I have been given the following question:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrjsI.png

I know how to expand out the RHS using the vector triple product, but I am unsure as to what I am meant to get to as I don't know how to differentiate the unit vector tangent in general. I tried differentiating using the chain rule but wasn't successful. Thanks

Comment: You might want to include more details.  Such as how is $T$ related to $r$, etc.

Comment: Hey sorry yeah, T hat is the unit vector tangent and has equation r'(t)/||r'(t)||

Answer (score 0):

Since $\vec T = \vec r'/||\vec r'||$, then
$$\frac{d\vec T}{dt} = \frac1{||\vec r'||^3}\left(||\vec r'||^2\vec r'' - \vec r'||\vec r'||\frac{d||\vec r'||}{dt}\right).$$
On the other hand,
$$RHS = \frac1{||\vec r'||^3}\left(||\vec r'||^2\vec r'' - \vec r'(\vec r'\cdot\vec r'')\right).$$
The final conclusion follows from the fact that
$$||\vec r'||\frac{d||\vec r'||}{dt} = \frac12\frac{d(\vec r'\cdot \vec r')}{dt} = \vec r'\cdot\vec r''.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot this makes sense now